# MassTransit Concurrency

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

We have been using mass transit for a while and have a few questions around the way concurrency works. We use the competing consumer pattern to pull messages off a queue and do some processing. We have noticed that increasing the number of processes increases performance as opposed to increasing threads. So for example 4 processes with 2 concurrent threads each gives better performance than 2 processes with 4 concurrent threads.

I think we may be getting a little mixed up with async. The work we do in the consumer is a COM call, which is synchronous, which we call in a thread. We may need to investigate this further.

So the question is whether it is expected we get better performance with multiple consumers as opposed to threads. We have just recently added metrics, but not sure at what we should be looking at to possible find the answer.

Comment: What do you call process? consumer?

Comment: Depending upon the transport, you can adjust the prefetch counts and/or max concurrent calls per receive endpoint to increase the number of active messages being processed. The defaults are conservative based on CPU core count.

Comment: So we have played around a bit with prefetch counts and maximum concurrent calls. We're not sure we have understood how this affects performance. We realize that too high a prefetch count may end up with competing consumers not having any work while a few consumers may have fetched all the remaining messages. We have experimented with increasing maximum concurrent calls, but don't quite understand why 1 consumer with say 16 maximum concurrent calls isn't anywhere near as performant as say 8 competing consumers with say a maximum of 2 concurrent calls.

Comment: What's the consumer doing? Heavy CPU consumers will scale out better than up once you reach the core count.

Comment: The consumer actually calls a COM object (legacy code). The work is a mixture of CPU and database access.